# jquery code is not working on ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

One function is not working on IE8 but working on google chrome and firefox.

XmlDom contain xml data

```
 $(XmlDom).find('Message').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id')==id)
        {
          msg=  $(this).find('messageText').text();

        }

    });
```

plz help

here is the sample data

```
      <Messages> 
      <Message id="4">      
      <messageText>text tenvcnvxtn.</messageText>
      </Message>
      <Message id="5">
      <messageText>text textn.</messageText>
      </Message>
    </Messages>
```

Comment: Any sample data. what is value of XmlDom?

Comment: fiddle is blocked in my office

Comment: Check the version of jQuery you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8, it use a HTML document. It will not recognize XML.
If you want to use the XML, you need to parse it by IE XML parser.

```
    var XmlDom = "<messages>" +
        "<message id=\"msg1\">" +
            "<messageText>message 1</messageText>" +
        "</message>" +
        "<message id=\"msg2\">" +
            "<messageText>message 2</messageText>" +
        "</message>" +
        "<message id=\"msg3\">" +
            "<messageText>message 3</messageText>" +
        "</message>" +
         "</messages>";
    var id = "msg2";
    var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xml.loadXML(XmlDom);

    if (xml.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
            var err = xml.parseError;
            console.log(err.reason);
    }

    $("messages", xml).find("message").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("id") == id) {
                    msg =  $(this).find("messageText").text();
                    console.log(msg);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

New versions of jQuery don't support IE8 or under. If you need to support them, use the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) or a version of jQuery that supports IE8.

1.9.1 for example.

> jQuery 1.x
>
> The jQuery 1.x line had major changes as of jQuery 1.9.0. We strongly
>   recommend that you also use the jQuery Migrate plugin if you are
>   upgrading from pre-1.9 versions of jQuery or need to use plugins that
>   haven't yet been updated. Read the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guid](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)e and the
>   [jQuery 1.9 release blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/) for more information.
>
> jQuery 2.x
>
> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. All the notes in the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade
>   Guide apply here as well. Since IE 6/7/8 are still relatively common,
>   we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8
>   users are visiting the site. Please read the [2.0 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)
>   carefully.